# Backdoor Roth IRA conversion deadline and taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, roth-ira, roth-conversion

I had no previous IRA accounts but this year I deposited $5,500 in March, 2016 into a 2015 Traditional IRA contribution. Then in that same month, I did a backdoor conversion to a Roth IRA account for that full amount.

Now after that, in the same month, I made a $5,500 2016 Traditional IRA contribution and did a Roth conversion for that full amount.

I think I declared the $5500 Traditional IRA on Form 8606 for my 2015 taxes. Should I declare the initial conversion this year along with my 2nd $5500 conversion or should the initial conversion have been declared on the 2015 taxes? I saw that there were deadlines for Roth conversions. Is my current situation affected by that at all or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversions to Roth always count under the calendar year they occurred. Both your conversions were done in 2016, so they should both be reported on your 2016 taxes only. In your case, neither conversion should have any tax, so it doesn't make a difference which year they count under.